# No orientation-related notifications are being fired. Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I want to be notified when the orientation of the device changes. I've setup a test method that's suppose to receive the notification. I'm trying several different observers to achieve that, and none of them are working. Why isn't testMethod being fired?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    // register for orientation change notification

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(testMethod)     name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(testMethod)
                                             name: UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                           object: nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(testMethod)
                                             name: UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                           object: nil];
}

- (void)testMethod
{
    NSLog(@"phone was rotated");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally had the rotation lock engaged on my phone. Always test on more than one phone!

Comment: awww and I was going to answer your question

Comment: I did the same thing! Such an easy thing to overlook, and it causes strange behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Orientation notification, which is UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification. Do not put it inside the @"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" because you dont know the actual content of the constant which is UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification. It appears you are using a view controller. You should use willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

Comment: I'm trying -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSLog(@"rotated");
} but its still not be fired

Answer (score 0):

end of the bool type something set the orientation .write return yes in all end of the view ..orientation in potrait and landscape mode takeplace